# In VIM, how do I create an alert when searching for text and the search loops from the end back to the beginning?

Tags: vim

I'd like the screen to flash, or similar, when searching for text and the search loops from the end of the buffer back to the beginning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the search jumps from end to top and finds the next entry, Vim displays

```
search hit BOTTOM, continuing at TOP
```

in the command line.

If this is not displayed for you, execute:

```
set shortmess-=s
```

This removes `s` from the `shortmess` option. For `s` the documentation (`:help 'shortmess'`) says:

> don't give "search hit BOTTOM, continuing at TOP" or "search
>   hit TOP, continuing at BOTTOM" messages

Comment: thank you. is there a way to use this alert to trigger an event like flashing the screen?

Comment: @John i don‘t think that this is possible